# Magento - 2.2.5 Possible Problems?

Tags: magento-2.2.5

Magento has released **Magento-2.2.5** version on **June 27, 2018**

This release includes :

**1**. Multiple enhancements to product security plus bug fixes and enhancements.

**2**. Check out the many community-contributed fixes.

**3**. Although this release includes these enhancements, no confirmed attacks related to these issues have occurred to date.

**4**. However, certain vulnerabilities can potentially be exploited to access customer information or take over administrator sessions.

So, Magento is recommending to upgrade our Magento software to the latest version as soon as possible.

**What are the Possible Issues with this release?**

Answer (score 2):

As per the release notes of Magento 2.2.5, these are the known issues of Magento 2.2.5:

**Known Issues:**
The Amazon Pay, Magento Shipping, and Vertex extensions have the following known issues:

**Amazon Pay known issues:**

- Clicking Save Config on the Payment Methods page while configuring
  your Amazon Pay settings can result in a JavaScript error.
  Workaround: Refresh the page.
- Magento throws the following exception during checkout if you
  disable Amazon Pay when installing Magento using the web wizard:
  Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Payment model name is not provided in config!. Note that this error occurs only if one or two of the three Amazon modules shipped with Magento are disabled.
  If all three Amazon modules are disabled, this problem does not occur. GitHub-16167
- Magento displays the Amazon Pay option during checkout with
  multiple addresses even though multi-shipping is not supported with Amazon Pay.
- Magento does not display the Amazon Pay button during checkout
  when the customer selects Klarna or PayPal as a payment method for an order containing a virtual product.
- Magento does not display the Amazon Pay button on the Checkout
  page if an order contains a virtual product.
- Customer cannot return to standard checkout flow by clicking the
  Return to standard checkout button.
- Customer cannot leave the Amazon Pay checkout page and return to
  the generic checkout page when an order contains virtual products.
- Customers cannot add a new shipping address to an order that
  contains virtual products.

**dotmailer known issues:**

The following Dotmailer behaviors have been observed when Magento Commerce for B2B is deployed with split databases:

- Customer, subscriber, and guest data are not being successfully
  synced. As a result, newly created contacts display the Not imported
  status in the contact report, and the relevant address books in
  dotmailer remain empty.
- Review remainder email cannot be sent to a subscribed customer if
  review remainder emails are not enabled for non-subscribed customers.
- Magento cannot send Customer and Guest Abandoned Cart email if these
  emails are not allowed for non-subscribed contacts.
- When a merchant clicks the Run Contact Sync button, Magento throws an
  exception when a merchant clicks the Run Contact Sync button.
- Magento throws an error during the creation of a subscriber or
  customer, but still creates the new subscriber or customer.

**Magento Shipping known issues:**

- A merchant can create multiple return shipments for an already
  shipped return.

**Vertex known issues:**

- The order amount on Vertex Cloud differs from the order information
  displayed by Magento when Catalog Price Rule is applied.
- Magento applies taxes to a custom price even when the Original Price
  only option from the Apply Tax On drop-down list has been selected.
- Magento displays an inaccurate Vertex API Status message when the
  Vertex Address Validation API Url and Vertex Validation Function
  fields contain invalid values.
- The Transaction Details reports and Transaction Summary reports have
  slight irregularities. Magento does not include product price and
  taxes in the Transaction Details Report “Gross Amount” and “Tax
  Amount” columns, and does not include product price in the
  Transaction Summary Report.
- The Vertex invoice has been sent message appears momentarily on the
  Review and Payments page, but not as expected on the Success page.
- When a customer places an order, Magento calculates the amount of tax
  and sends a Vertex invoice even when the Company Information tab is
  missing the company street, company city, and company postal code.
- Magento does not display the Vertex invoice has been sent message as
  expected when the payment method is Authorize.net and the order
  status is Suspect Fraud.
- Magento does not display the Vertex customer code field on the All
  Customers page as expected, which undermines the ability to filter by
  customer code.
- Magento does not display the tax section of the Order Summary that is
  included on the Review and Payments page during checkout when the
  shopping cart includes a virtual product.

Answer (score 0):

The order view of backend Sales->Orders has error: Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.

Please fix the problem ASAP!!